# Show a few columns in a stored procedure based on a parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a parameter in my stored procedure called internal. If "internal" = yes then I want to display an additional 2 columns in my results. If it's no I don't want to display these columns.

I can do a case statement and then I can set the column to be empty but the column name will still be returned in the results.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way not to return these 2 columns in the results at all?
2. Can I do it in one case statement and not a separate case statement for each column?

Thank you

Comment: KISS - Why not just have 2 select statements within an if/else?  You can absract some of the logic to a view if needed.

Comment: **No**, `CASE` is a function, and can only return a single value.

Comment: @AlexK. The issue with 2 select statements are that it's a major complicated select statement and I really don't want to have to have the whole select statement twice

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader is there a different function I can use instead of case?

Comment: You can't optionally hide columns in a single select. You can only set their values to NULL,

Comment: Where is this sproc being called from? Surely users aren't directly querying your stored procedure? In the application calling this, hide the columns even if you do bring them back or leave them blank.

Comment: @Jeremy It's some kind of generic program that displays all columns returned in the query

Comment: modify the program?

Comment: it's an idea, but I was hoping to do it within the procedure, because the program run hundreds of procedures and I didn't want to customize it for one procedure.

Comment: if you can't modify the program and you REALLY have to not include even the column names, another option is dynamic SQL, but depending on the complexity of your SQL statement, you could be introducing extra problems

Comment: thanks, I'll probably just have to do dynamic SQL. Thank you

Comment: Please read this article thoroughly. It is a long but comprehensive read about dynamic sql http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Put the complex select in a view, then `if cond select a,b,c from view else select a,b,c,d from view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, `CASE` is a function, and can only return a single value.

And According to your comment:-

> The issue with 2 select statements are that it's a major complicated
>   select statement and I really don't want to have to have the whole
>   select statement twice.

so you can use the next approach for avoid duplicate code:-

```
Create procedure proc_name (@internal char(3), .... others)
as
BEGIN
    declare @AddationalColumns varchar(100)
    set @AddationalColumns = ''

    if @internal = 'Yes'
        set @AddationalColumns = ',addtionalCol1 , addtionalCol2'

        exec ('Select 
                col1, 
                col2,
                col3' 
                + @AddationalColumns +
                'From
                    tableName
                Where ....
                ' )
END
```

Comment: thanks, this is dynamic SQL but I guess it's my best option

Answer (score 0):

Try IF Condition

```
IF(internal = 'yes')
BEGIN
    SELECT (Columns) FROM Table1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT (Columns With additional 2 columns) FROM Table1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this solution. It allows you to keep only one copy of code if it's so important but you will have to deal with dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE tab (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT);
GO

DECLARE @internal BIT = 0, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @sql = N'SELECT col1 ' + (SELECT CASE @internal WHEN 1 THEN N', col2, col3 ' ELSE N'' END) + N'FROM tab'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO

DROP TABLE tab
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a 'wrapper' proc. Keep your current one untouched.
Create a new proc which executes this (pseudo code):

```
create proc schema.wrapperprocname (same @params as current proc)

as

begin

Create table #output (column list & datatypes from current proc);

insert into #output
exec schema.currentproc (@params)

if @internal = 'Yes'
select * from #output
else
select columnlist without the extra 2 columns from #output

end
```

This way the complex select statement remains encapsulated in the original proc.
Your only overhead is keeping the #output table & select lists in in this proc in sync with any changes to the original proc.

IMO it's also easier to understand/debug/tune than dynamic sql.